# Symfony Form: Set default/value on error?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

My crazy designer would like the message "Required" displaying (in red) inside a field if the form has been submitted and it is invalid because of an empty field.

The form in question is a login prompt and I'm using a custom class that extends sfGuardFormSignin

I've managed to set the value and add a class with..

```
$this->widgetSchema['username']->setAttribute('class','red');
$this->widgetSchema['username']->setDefault('Required');
```

..but how do I do this only when the username field is invalid and because of the Required error?

I assume it's the same for the password field?

Many thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the advice greg0ire. I've had a play with that but the formatRow method of sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter doesn't seem to be getting hit. Is this because my form extends sfGuardFormSignin and using the sfGuardAuth plugin?

```
class FrontendsfGuardFormSignin extends sfGuardFormSignin
{
  public function configure()
  {
    parent::configure();

    // This works!
    $this->widgetSchema['username']->setLabel('Email');

    // I copied this from the link you pasted
    $decorator = new myWidgetFormSchemaFormatterCustom($this->getWidgetSchema());
    $this->widgetSchema->addFormFormatter('custom', $decorator);
    $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('custom');
  }
}
```

/lib/widget/myWidgetFormSchemaFormatterCustom.class.php

```
class myWidgetFormSchemaFormatterCustom extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter
{

  public function __construct(sfWidgetFormSchema $widgetSchema)
  {
    parent::__construct($widgetSchema);
  }

  public function formatRow($label, $field, $errors = array(), $help = '', $hiddenFields = null)
  {
    // Nothing happens!?
    var_dump($errors);
    die();
    parent::formatRow($label, $field, $errors, $help, $hiddenFields);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$widget->render(array('value' => $widget->getError()));
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, you were right. I could handle what I needed in the template rather than creating custom widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Designers have such crazy ideas...

You'll have to [write a custom schema formatter](http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/7-days-of-symfony-1-1-forms-widgets-and-validators-day7) to do this. You'll probably have to override [the `formatRow()` method](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter#method_formatrow) to achieve this.

Analyse the `$errors` array argument of this method, and if you spot the "Required" error in it, then do your special stuff. You won't need to use the code you posted in your question.